# Is there a way to call a method after building a fragment?

Tags: java, android

I want to change a Fregment and as soon as the Gui is built a method should be executed.

I have solved it so far with a thread. Only I thought that there would have to be a better way.
OnResume () is executed before the fragment is formed.
Does anyone know a way that without a thread to solve?

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragmentRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_l2c_printersettings, container, false);
    fragmentRoot.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    fragmentRoot.requestFocus();

    ...
    ...
    ...

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                loadPrinter(); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return fragmentRoot;
}
```

Comment: What about the `onViewCreated` method? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%2520android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for `public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` in your fragment.

## Fragment lifecycle.

[image]

[From the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle))

> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving views or restoring state. It is also useful for fragments that use setRetainInstance(boolean) to retain their instance, as this callback tells the fragment when it is fully associated with the new activity instance. This is called after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) and before onViewStateRestored(Bundle).

Comment: The same problem as onResume()  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) is executed before the fragment is formed.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function in `onViewCreated`. By the time `onViewCreated` is called, the fragment is completely loaded.

Comment: Same Problem. Still the first fragment 
in the foreground when the method is called.

Comment: Can you post the body of loadPrinter() as well?